# Can forms authentication ignore returnUrl

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Is there an easy way to get forms authentication to ignore the returnURL?

So the user clicks a link, the site timesout, they get redirected to my login page (which appends ReturnUrl to the URL) - I don't want this to happen, or for it to be ignored when they login again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to have some code in your login form's code-behind that does the following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["returnUrl"]))
{
    Response.Redirect("path/to/my/login.aspx");
}
```

In other words, check in your login page for the presence of the returnUrl querystring parameter and if it's present, strip it out by redirecting back to yourself.

Comment: Isn't that a little ...expensive?

Answer (score 4):

You can strip it off if you don't want to show it. I do that because I don't want it to show with SEO-friendly URLs that I have setup.

In the `Global.asax` file put the following:

```
Protected Sub Application_EndRequest(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim redirectUrl As String = Me.Response.RedirectLocation
        If Not Me.Request.RawUrl.Contains("ReturnUrl=") AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUrl) Then
            Me.Response.RedirectLocation = Regex.Replace(redirectUrl, "\?ReturnUrl=(?'url'[^&]*)", String.Empty)
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can prevent this from being tacked onto the URL when using Forms Authentication.

However, you don't *need* to call [`RedirectFromLoginPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f5z1yty.aspx) (which is what I'll presume you're doing at the minute); what you can do is simply use [`SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) to persist the login state and [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) anywhere you like after that.